# EC2 Break even point analysis

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, capacity-planning, statistics

I'm doing capacity planning for my DR site and i'm trying to understand break-even point for Light/Medium/Heavy reserved instances vs the Ondemand. I have plotted my values on a graph as shown in the picture below:

[image: http://imgur.com/wLAOIX1]

Am i correct,in making the following assertions ?

1. For an **m3.large** instance running 24/7 (100% utilization),there is no break-even point and does it makes sense to prefer an **Ondemand** over **light RI** ?
2. The break-even point for a High RI over Ondemand is some where around 170 days. Am i right in saying,choosing High RI pays dividends only if,the uptime of that instance is more than 170 days or 4080 Hours (46.44 %) in an year?

Comment: If you're running 24/7, it's not "light usage". If you're running less than 46% of a year, it's not "heavy usage".  There's a reason they picked these terms.

Comment: You do realise that for most organisations a disaster recovery site is actually mostly idle and only active during a the actual disaster (typically those are of relatively short duration) and during fail-over tests?

Comment: @HBruijn I don't believe it's a software license issue ...just an understanding of the Amazon EC2 types.

Comment: @NathanC That has been used as the closing reason for a number of other questions that deal with cloud pricing, which IMHO this seems to be a variant of.

Comment: @LOL there are a couple of different math and logical errors in your graph.

Comment: Can you point those please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it 100% of the time, use heavy utilization for the highest discount rates. However, if it's going to be a disaster recovery solution, you might as well use "light utilization" unless the higher price (for longer periods) and uncertain capacity of on-demand is enough for you.

The major difference is that with on demand, you're not *promised* capacity, so it can throw your entire DR setup out the window, hence why reserved instances exist. However, the upfront cost is a deterrent...